# returning NULL in cost string& function

Tags: c++

I need to write my own hash map on C++. It has a method .get("some_string") if this string is not in my hash_map I return NULL. But I cant check in my program if this function returned NULL or string. This is my code:

```
if (m.get("some_string"))
    cout << m.get("some_string");
```

and method:

```
const string& Map::get(const string& s) {
    string_node* pos = find_pos(s);

    if (pos)
        return pos->val;
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

pos->val is just a string. So I have an error that I cant convert from const string to bool.
The question is what I need to do, to prevent errors in `cout` then my functions returns `NULL`. How can I check it?

Comment: When you `return NULL;` you get undefined behavior here. The function has to construct a `string` object to return, and it does so using `NULL` as an argument to `string`'s constructor. This invokes `string`'s `char *` constructor, which has a precondition that it not be passed a null pointer. Thus you get get UB as a result of the precondition violation. Plus you should be getting a warning about returning a reference to a local object, which will return a dangling reference. You should be compiling with warnings enabled and you should pay attention to the warnings you get.

Comment: @bames53 I thought NULL is defined as 0 and string doesn't have implicit constructor to take an integer so wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @bames53 I have a warning when I write something like `return ""`, but where is no warning when I write `return NULL`. And it compiles and when I return `NULL` in `find_pos` variable `pos` is `0` so I can write `if (pos)`

Comment: @NeilKirk but it does compile

Comment: Even if it compiles I guarantee it's not doing what you think/want it to do.

Comment: @NeilKirk but why then `return NULL` in `string_node* find_pos` works? When I `return NULL` where `pos` is equal to `0` and I can write `if (pos)` to check was it `NULL` or not.

Comment: _"I need to write my own hash map on C++"_ No you don't

Comment: @Neil `NULL` converts to `const char*` innit. This is why `nullptr` exists and everybody should be using it.

Comment: @Dima: Because a `string_node*` is not even remotely the same as a `const std::string&`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit so does it mean I can normally use `return NULL` in `string_node* find_pos` but cant in `const string& get`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit _"No you don't"_ yes, and my mark would be 0.

Comment: @Dima: `NULL` is a valid initialiser for a `string_node*`. It is not a valid initialiser for a `std::string`.

Comment: @Dima Take a look at this [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f5c8bb85f44f36f). This shows the compiler warning you should be getting (and if you're not getting it then you should either turn up the warning level on your compiler or get a new compiler). Also, if you can figure out why the program's output is what it is then hopefully you'll understand what's wrong with treating `string_node *` the same as `const string &`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Unfortunately `nullptr` doesn't solve this problem; `nullptr` converts to `const char *` too.

Answer (score 6):

You CANNOT return a null value for a `const string&`. You must return a reference to a real string object which will continue living after the function has returned.

Options:

- Return a `const string *` which can be null
- Throw an exception in the null case.
- Return a string by value, and return an empty (but valid) string in the null case. This has two disadvantages. It copies the results and you can no longer discern between the null case and a genuine empty string value, without outputting more information from the function some how.

Comment: I think an empty string may also be an option. that is what std::map do.

Comment: Or use an output parameter and return a bool whether it is successful.

Comment: @clcto There is no reason to do that, as a pointer can already convey null-ness and does not force the value to be copied.

Comment: @SHR Added info about returning empty string.

Comment: @SHR: Not quite. `std::map` creates an empty element then returns it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: So does the hashmap in the standard, `std::unordered_map<>`. It seems reasonable to have consistent semantics even when implementing your own hashmap. (Of course, 99.9% of the hashmaps need at most a custom hash function - the need for a full reimplementation is rare)

Comment: @MSalters: Right, that's what I'm saying!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just said you not always want to throw exception when don't have an error. When failed to find a key in a map, is not necessarily considered as an error, that is why throwing exception is wrong solution if you ask me. the right thing is to return an empty string, or have an option to define Not Exist string answer. Also need another function to tell if key exists or not (like: `map::find`).

Comment: @SHR If an empty string can be returned as a legitimate result, then I really don't like returning it as the only indication of no result.

Comment: @SHR: I'm not persuaded that you understood my comment.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what is the difference if you add it with empty string, or just return the empty string? In both cases you've got empty string. The only reason to add non existed searched key to the map is to improve performance, if you'll search it again.

Comment: @SHR: Ehm, in one case your container is now one element bigger than it was before.... _"The only reason to add non existed searched key to the map is to improve performance, if you'll search it again"_ No it's not.

Answer (score 1):

References cannot be null so it makes no sense to return `NULL` from the function. Likewise, you are using a `const string&` as a conditional, so it tries to convert it to a bool, but there is no suitable conversion. Instead, return an empty string and check if the return value is equal to that:

```
if (pos)
    return pos->value;
else
    return "";


if( m.get("some_string") == "" ) { ... }
```

If an empty string is a valid value then you can use a output parameter:

```
bool Map::try_get( const string& key, string& value )
{
    string_node* pos = find_pos(s);

    if (pos)
    {
        value = pos->val;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
       value = "";
       return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if an empty string is a valid value to store in this map?

Comment: I don't think an empty string would ever show up as a hash.

Comment: @sgtHale Making assumptions is the fastest way to bugs.

Comment: Better, though note that this will force the value to be copied into the string referenced by the `value` parameter, which may not be necessary. Leave it up to the caller to determine if a copy should be made and just return a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return NULL if you are returning a reference. You could have a special return case though. Have it return an empty string reference signifying that the hash doesn't exist.

Comment: What if an empty string is a valid value to store in this map?

Comment: Then don't use an empty string. Of course it's gonna end up getting dictated by how specific the implementation is. But knowing if your hash function can return an empty string is probably something you should know even if you CONSIDER returning such a special case.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle an optional return value is to use [`Boost.Optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/quick_start.html#boost_optional.quick_start.optional_return_values). You can simply use it like this:

```
boost::optional<std::string> Map::get(const std::string& s) {
     // ...
}

int main()
{
    if (boost::optional<std::string> os = map.get("asdf"))
    {
        // *os
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) The return type should be `boost::optional<std::string>` (neither const, nor a reference). (2) Note that this approach will cause the value to be copied in order to be returned by value, which will result in a performance penalty.

Comment: @cdhow I originally had that but had trouble reproducing OP's example.